# Как правильно написать сеттеры и геттеры

Tags: javascript, getter, setter

Код выдает синтаксическую ошибку в **vscode** и **playcode**. В чем ошибка понять никак не могу.

```js
function Counter() {

  this.number = 0

  get minus() {
    this.number = this.number - 1;
  }

  get plus() {
    this.number += 1;
  }

  set render(number) {
    h1.innerHTML = this.number;
  }
}
```

Comment: Напишите в место get set слово function

Comment: мне нужно использовать getter / setter

Comment: Тогда делайте так https://learn.javascript.ru/descriptors-getters-setters

Comment: Геттеры и сеттеры определяются к свойствам/ полям. Это специальные методы требующие специального синтаксиса

Comment: читал, не могу понять что с моим синтаксисом не так

Comment: А не чо что у вас нет таких полей чтоб писат геттер и сеттер?

Comment: не понимаю, каких полей?
вы мне написали несколько предложений и ни в одном из них нет ответа, 
но все равно спасибо за внимание

Comment: Вы пытаетесь внутри функции применить синтаксис классов, поэтому получаете ошибку. Для функций используется синтаксис через прототипы, для классов синтаксис который вы делаете, они разные. Два примера можно увидеть тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38367797/9033215

Answer (score 1):

Пример того как надо писать и использовать геттеры и сеттеры.

```js
class Counter {

  constructor() {
    this._number = 0;
  }


  get number() {
    console.log('Было обращение к свойству number!');

    return this._number;
  }

  set number(value) {
    // Можно навесить дополнителную логику
    // Для примера выведим сообщение от том, что мы обновили свойство number

    console.log('Свойство number - обновлено!');
    this._number = value;
  }

  plus() {

    this.number++;

    return this;
  }

  minus() {

    this.number--;

    return this;
  }

  render() {
    document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = this.number;
  }
}

const counter = new Counter();

counter
  .plus()
  .plus()
  .minus()
  .render();
```

```html
<span class="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Геттеры и сетторы можно объявлять только внутри определения класса и литерала объекта.

В примере в вопросе, идет попытка определить геттер внутри функции, что является синтаксической ошибкой.

Для решения нужно либо переписать с использованием классов, либо использовать литерал объекта, например:

```js
var Counter = {

  number: 0,

  get minus() {
    return this.number - 1;
  },

  get plus() {
    return this.number + 1;
  },

  set render(number) {
    this.number = number;
  }
}

Counter.render = 10;

console.log(Counter.number)
console.log(Counter.minus)
console.log(Counter.plus)
```